# Searching for SharePoint Documents by Custom Column Value using Microsoft Graph API from Postman

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, postman, customcolumn

How can I use the Microsoft Graph API from Postman to search for documents within all SharePoint sites in an organization based on a specific value in a custom column? I am currently not getting the expected results when making the request:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search?$filter=listItem/all(d:d/fields/UniqueCustomID eq '081212')
```

The documents that have this custom column value are not being returned in the API response. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

You need to send `POST` request to `/search/query` endpoint.

In the body specify the type of entities to be searched and in the query you can scope the query to only those with unique custom id.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "entityTypes": [
        "listItem"
      ],
      "query": {
        "queryString": "UniqueCustomID=081212"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

`"queryString": "UniqueCustomID=081212"`: `=` has meaning equals

`"queryString": "UniqueCustomID:081212"`: `:` has meaning contains

Documentation

[Search content in SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-files)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I try your example the result I get from the API starts with {"value":[{"searchTerms":["UniqueCustomID","081212"],... 


So it doesn't actually search the customcolumn values. The files I expect to get aren't listed, it just searches everything for the keywords 'UniqueCustomID' and '081212'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @cb0008 looks like that search API doesn't support filtering by custom field.

Comment: @cb0008 Is your custom column indexed?

Comment: The custom column wasn't indexed. But I just had it indexed just now by following the steps on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview . The result is still the same unfortunately.

Comment: If the API doesn't support the custom-column values, is there maybe a different way to do this, for example is the SharePoint Search REST API (not Microsoft Graph API) the way it should be done?

Answer (score 0):

The final solution involved this:

- Changing the post-request as shown in the answer by user2250152.
- Following the steps in this article: https://support.shortpoint.com/support/solutions/articles/1000304547-how-to-identify-custom-property-names-in-sharepoint
- Changing the 'Search Schema' to enable Query, Search and Retrieve.
- Re-indexing the document library as it is explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/crawl-site-content